# Reduction of order - Differential Equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem:

$$yy''+ (y')^2 = 1$$

I know I have to use: $y' = z$ and $y'' = z \frac{dz}{dy}$

but I'm not getting the answer which is: $$y^2 = c_1 + (x + c_2)^2$$

Please **help**

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try the substitution $w(x) = y(x)^2$, and calculate what $w''(x)$ in terms of $y(x)$ and its derivatives.